# PHP and Array_round spiteful function

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm trying to create a function to pick up words from a text file randomly, and no one here poblema. The problem arises when I try to verify if the user correctly inserts the words. Unfortunately, I always get a negative answer. From what I understood when called, the function can not save the contents into the variable that naturally remains empty.

```
<?php

function random_word() {
    $dictionary = "dictionary.txt";
    $word = file($dictionary);
    $n = 0;
    while ($n < 2) {
        $n++;
        $randomword = array_rand($word);
        echo $word[$randomword];
    }
}

$a = random_word();
echo "-----------------";
echo $a;

?>
```

If I try to check the $a variable it tells me that it is NULL. I'm sure the problem is the function but I know PHP shortly and I'm struggling to find the error.

Comment: your function doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something. Not sure if you want to return a string or an array but your code seems to be made for string.

```
<?php

function random_word() {
    $dictionary = "dictionary.txt";
    $word = file($dictionary);
    $n = 0;
    while ($n < 2) {
        $n++;
        $randomword = array_rand($word);
        $returner .= $word[$randomword] . " ";
    }
    return trim($returner);
}

$a = random_word();
echo "-----------------";
echo $a;

?>
```

Comment: @GeckyXV No problem. Please accept the answer if it is correct.